# ¿Porqué no se visualiza el CheckBox en Chrome?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, google-chrome, checkbox

Estoy creando un formulario y necesito varios `CheckBox`, los he puesto pero no consigo visualizarlos en Chrome (en Firefox e Internet Explorer sí se visualizan), no sé si me faltará algo o mi error se debe a otra cosa. El código para el `CheckBox` es este: `<asp:CheckBox runat="server" />`. Un código simple ya que lo que busco de momento es que se visualice en el formulario.

```
<code>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>¿Vino el cliente?</td>
        <td>
            <asp:DropDownList runat="server">
                <asp:ListItem>Prueba1</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>Prueba2</asp:ListItem>
            </asp:DropDownList>
        </td>
        <td>(ms)</td>
        <td>
            <asp:TextBox runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Prueba</td>
        <td>
            <asp:DropDownList runat="server">
                <asp:ListItem>Prueba1</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>Prueba2</asp:ListItem>
            </asp:DropDownList>
        </td>
        <td>Caudal</td>
        <td>
            <asp:TextBox runat="server">< /asp:TextBox>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Pureba< /td>
        <td>
            <asp:DropDownList runat="server">
                <asp:ListItem>Prueba1</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>Prueba2</asp:ListItem>
            </asp:DropDownList>
         </td>
         <td>Cobertura</td>
         <td>
            <asp:TextBox runat="server"></asp:TextBox> / <asp:TextBox runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>Prueba</td>
         <td>
             <asp:DropDownList runat="server">
                <asp:ListItem>Prueba1< /asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>Prueba2< /asp:ListItem>
             </asp:DropDownList>
         </td>
         <td>Cobertura< /td>
         <td>
            <asp:TextBox runat="server"></asp:TextBox> / <asp:TextBox runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>Prueba</td>
         <td>
             <asp:DropDownList runat="server">
                <asp:ListItem>Prueba1</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>Prueba2</asp:ListItem>
             </asp:DropDownList>
         </td>
         <td>Cobertura</td>
         <td>
            <asp:TextBox runat="server"></asp:TextBox> / <asp:TextBox runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>Prueba</td>
         <td>
             <asp:DropDownList runat="server">
                <asp:ListItem>Prueba1</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>Prueba2</asp:ListItem>
             </asp:DropDownList>
         </td>
         <td>Alarma< /td>
         <td>
             <asp:CheckBox runat="server"/>
         </td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
         <td>Prueba</td>
         <td>
             <asp:DropDownList runat="server">
                <asp:ListItem>Prueba1</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>Prueba2</asp:ListItem>
             </asp:DropDownList>
         </td>
                        <td>Fax</td>
                        <td>
                           <asp:CheckBox runat="server" /> 
                        </td>
                    </tr>
       <tr>
         <td>Prueba</td>
         <td>
             <asp:DropDownList runat="server">
                <asp:ListItem>Prueba1</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>Prueba2</asp:ListItem>
             </asp:DropDownList>
         </td>
                        <td>TPV</td>
                        <td>
                           <asp:CheckBox runat="server" />                           
                        </td>
                    </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>Prueba</td>
         <td>
             <asp:DropDownList runat="server">
                <asp:ListItem>Prueba1</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>Prueba2</asp:ListItem>
             < /asp:DropDownList>
         </td>
         <td>(Mbps)</td>
         <td>
            <asp:TextBox runat="server"></asp:TextBox> / <asp:TextBox runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>Prueba</td>
         <td>
             <asp:DropDownList runat="server">
                <asp:ListItem>Prueba1</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>Prueba2</asp:ListItem>
             </asp:DropDownList>
         </td>
         <td>Mbps)</td>
         <td>
            <asp:TextBox runat="server"></asp:TextBox> / <asp:TextBox runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
         </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>               
        <td>Prueba</td>
        <td>
            <asp:TextBox runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        </td>                        
    </tr>                    
</table>
</code>
```

Las imágenes del CSS de la herramienta de desarrollador:

[image: Primera imagen del código css]

[image: Segunda imagen del código css]

Comment: Que navegador estas usando?

Comment: Estoy usando Chrome

Comment: Pues escombrar si desde Internet Explorer y firefox se ven?

Comment: Si, en ambos, edito el post para especificarlo

Comment: Probablemente deberías poner el código completo. Es posible que tengas algún error tipográfico (por ejemplo,alguna etiqueta mal cerrada) que puede estar provocando el problema, y sin ver el código es imposible apreciarlo

Comment: No puedo poner el código completo, es de una empresa. De todas formas, creo que si fuera por una etiqueta mal cerrada me daría error o no se visualizaría en el resto de navegadores.

Comment: No tienes por que dar el código exacto, solo un [mcve] que podamos probar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al final he conseguido resolver el problema. Sólo tuve que añadirle un `Width` y un `Height` al `CheckBox` como muestro a continuación:

```
<asp:CheckBox runat="server" Height="15" Width="15"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Creo que  posiblemente tengas por tu css un código parecido a esto aplicado a los checkbox:

```
-webkit-appearance: none;
```

para solucionarlo puedes o bien eliminarlo  o añadir esto en tu css para tus checkbox:

```
input[type=checkbox]
{
   -webkit-appearance:checkbox;
}
```

Comment: Parece que no, he probado a cambiarlo (de todas formas no lo aseguro 100%, este código que me han dado tiene css por todas partes, pero casi fijo no)

Comment: has probado mediante la inspección de desarrolladores de Chrome a buscar el checkbox y ver las propiedades de css que tiene aplicadas? de ser así podrías ponerlas o subir una imagen de ellas?